# Bash Script won't run as cron.hourly Job in Centos 8

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos

So I made an script named ***rsync-job*** that runs when manually executed. When I copy it to the /etc/cron.hourly directory, it will not run. I checked crontab -e and deleted any jobs in there.

[image]

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -azvp /home/username/Documents/ 192.168.1.160:/tmp/backups
```

Not sure what I am missing, greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is it with the exutable flag?

Comment: Why not using crontab?  * */1  * * *  /path/to/yourcmd

Comment: @ensarman Not sure what you mean, A bit new to linux!

Comment: i tried crontab -e it wouldnt run through crontab neither!

Comment: And can you call anything else with crontab, e.g. a script containing only the ls command?

Comment: It's likely running but the `rsync` command is having an issue.  I would suggest you redirect the output of the command to a file which will 1) allow you to confirm it's really running and 2) see what the problem is.  Just add the following to the end of your command `> /tmp/rsync_hourly 2>&1`

Comment: Have you set the rsa key for ssh for root?

Comment: @JeffCrackalack permisson to  execute, but you have put the image, and it is with the executable falg

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This page is dedicated to questions about software development.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue!! i created under username jay and I'm assuming cron.hourly runs as root!